# How to connect to Flask-WebSocket server?

Tags: python, flask, xampp, flask-sockets

I am following this tutorial to try and use `Flask-WebSockets` in my app.

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent

My problem is that I don't know how to properly connect to the server.

When I make calls to my flask app, they are in the form:

**`http://localhost:80/myapp/<route_goes_here>`**

My app is structured as follows:

```
couponmonk/venv/couponmonk
    __init__.py
    views.py
    templates/
        index.html
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import *
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit       

app = Flask(__name__)    
socketio = SocketIO(app)                                                                                                                             
engine =  create_engine('mysql://root:my_password@localhost/my_db_name') 
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

import couponmonk.views
```

**views.py**

```
from couponmonk import app, DBSession, socketio

@socketio.on('my event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': message['data']})


@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Given my setup, where should I put this line:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

I'm also not sure what address to put for the following line in `index.html`:

**index.html**

The code in this file is identical to this (https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/example/templates/index.html)

```
var socket = io.connect('what to put here?');
```

I've tried `http://localhost:80/test` and get no response. I'm not sure if the `namespace` should be part of the address or not.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var socket = io.connect('what to put here?');
```

Is JavaScript, so that'll need to go into a `<script>` tag somewhere, probably your `head`.

In the tutorial, scroll to **A SocketIO Client** - this section starts talking about the client side of the websocket: the JavaScript.

We can also look at the [example's code on GitHub](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/tree/master/example) to see [that section](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/example/templates/index.html#L8). Finally, the [documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) also has HTML in the second code section.